# Batch - Find Out Permutation

Tags: batch-file, combinations, permutation

I am new to Batch and I would like to know if I can find out all combinations of numbers in order.

In this case I have 49 Numbers from 1 - 49 , and I have to pick 6 Numbers to be the results.

For example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 7 
...
1 2 3 4 5 49 
1 2 3 4 6 7 
1 2 3 4 6 8
```

etc...

This is my old code:

```bat
@echo off > NEWFILE & setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=44
set b=45
set c=46
set d=47
set e=48
set f=49
for /L %%a in (1 1 !a!) do (
for /L %%b in (2 1 !b!) do (
for /L %%c in (3 1 !c!) do (
for /L %%d in (4 1 !d!) do (
for /L %%e in (5 1 !e!) do (
for /L %%f in (6 1 !f!) do (
echo.%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f 
))))))) >> NEWFILE
goto :EOF
```

However it returns:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 7
...
1 2 3 4 5 49
1 2 3 4 6 6
```

Two 6's appeared.

I don't seem to be able to fix it, please help, thanks very much!

Comment: The way to "close" a question is given feedback to the answers and select one as Best Answer; doing that mark the question as "answered" and give reputation points to both the OP and the answerer. Adding "CLOSED" or any other similar banner to the question title is a practice not used in this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you post a question you should post your efforts to solve it, describe the method used and the problems you had; otherwise you may get similar answers with no explanations at all, like this one:

**EDIT**: As users dbenham and aschipfl indicated, my original code have a small bug: the `set /A i=M-1` line should be placed *after* the `:nextSet` label. This is the right code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "N=%1"
set "M=%2"

set "line="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%M%) do (
   set "C[%%i]=%%i"
   set "line=!line! ^!C[%%i]^!"
)

:nextSet
   set /A i=M-1
   for /L %%j in (!C[%M%]!,1,%N%) do (
      set "C[%M%]=%%j"
      echo %line%
   )

   :nextPos
   set "C=!C[%i%]!"
   if %C% equ %N% (
      set /A i-=1
      if !i! equ 0 goto :EOF
      goto nextPos
   )
   for /L %%i in (%i%,1,%M%) do (
      set /A C+=1,C[%%i]=C
   )
   if !C[%M%]! gtr %N% goto nextPos

goto nextSet
```

Obviously, the corrected code generate a much larger number of results and this version is particularly slow... **`:(`**

The new version below use the exact same code of dbenham's solution; its only advantage is that you may change the parameters used to generate the result in a very easy way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "N=%1"
set "M=%2"

set /A j=N-M, prev=0
set "for=" & set "line=" & set "endfor="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%M%) do (
   set /A j+=1
   set "for=!for! set /A start=!prev!+1 & for /L %%%%i in (^!start^!,1,!j!) do ("
   set "line=!line! %%%%i"
   set "endfor=!endfor!)"
   set "prev=%%%%i"
)
REM ECHO !FOR! echo !LINE! %ENDFOR%
%for% echo %line% %endfor%
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test.bat 6 4
 1 2 3 4
 1 2 3 5
 1 2 3 6
 1 2 4 5
 1 2 4 6
 1 2 5 6
 1 3 4 5
 1 3 4 6
 1 3 5 6
 1 4 5 6
 2 3 4 5
 2 3 4 6
 2 3 5 6
 2 4 5 6
 3 4 5 6
```

To get your results, use: `test.bat 49 6`

**2ND EDIT**: Faster method added

When the problem to solve is the excessive time a process takes, an obvious alternative is to use a faster programming language. The solution below use [JScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yek4tbz0(v=vs.84).aspx), that is somewhat similar to Batch file programming:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
echo Start: %time%
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" > result.txt
echo End:   %time%
goto :EOF

@end

// JScript code section

for ( var A=1; A <= 44; ++A ) {
   for ( var B=A+1; B <= 45; ++B ) {
      for ( var C=B+1; C <= 46; ++C ) {
         for ( var D=C+1; D <= 47; ++D ) {
            for ( var E=D+1; E <= 48; ++E ) {
               for ( var F=E+1; F <= 49; ++F ) {
                  WScript.Echo(A,B,C,D,E,F);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is a Batch-JScript hybrid script; save it with .BAT extension. This program took a little less than 9 minutes in my cheap-and-slow lap-top computer to generate a 239 MB file with 13983816 lines.

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with your algorithm. The correct result should have 13,983,816 lines, not 4,774. I notice your output only has 39 lines where the 2nd value is 3 when called with arguments of 49 and 6.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the fix should be quite simple: moving the label `:nextSet` up one line to appear before the line `set /A i=M-1`.

Comment: For the sake of performance, I was about to suggest the following changes: 1. move line `set "C=!C[%i%]!"` after the `if %C%` block; 2. insert `set /A C=C[%i%]+i-M` after label `:nextPos`; 3. replace `if %C% equ %N%` by `if %C% gtr %N%`; 4. delete line `if !C[%M%]! gtr %N%`; however, although these changes avoid additional `goto` loops and multiple `for /L %%i` loops, they make the code slower by about 65% on my computer strangely (redirecting the output to `nul` and using arguments `20` and `5`). Do you know why is this? Is `set /A` a so slow beast?

Comment: @dbenham You are right! I misplaced a line in the code (and in my mind **`:(`**). @aschipfl: there is no way to make this code faster; see my edit...

Comment: @Aacini I will fix the problem , thanks for your advice!

Comment: @Aacini The problem is fixed now !

Comment: @Aacini I ran the new edit as a batch file and my pc lagged so much when I opend result.txt

Comment: Well, that usually happens when you open a 239 MB file with Notepad! Try to use another, more efficient text editor...

Comment: Did this code generated the right results in a short amount of time? If so, may I ask you to select it as Best Answer (and also upvote it)?

Comment: @Aacini That code worked just fine , I'll upvote and select as best answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is compute intensive, given that there are 13,983,816 unique permutations. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_mathematics#Calculation_explained_in_choosing_6_from_49.)

The Rojo answer should work, but the GOTO and repetitive FOR /F parsing and IF logic will slow things down considerably.

The code is much faster if you use nested FOR /L loops.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%A in (1 1 44) do (
  set /a start=%%A+1
  for /l %%B in (!start! 1 45) do (
    set /a start=%%B+1
    for /l %%C in (!start! 1 46) do (
      set /a start=%%C+1
      for /l %%D in (!start! 1 47) do (
        set /a start=%%D+1
        for /l %%E in (!start! 1 48) do (
          set /a start=%%E+1
          for /l %%F in (!start! 1 49) do (
            echo %%A %%B %%C %%D %%E %%F
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

This will still be unbearably slow to let this script print the results to the screen. I estimate it will take 1.25 hours on my machine. Redirecting the output to a file is about 5 times faster, around 15 minutes.

Comment: I had just written this nested `for /L` loop solution exactly, but was prevented from posting by a damn phone call.  When I comment out the `echo` statement it completes in just like 5 minutes or so, fwiw.  Anyway, +1.

Comment: @rojo I tried out both ways and find both works , but dbenham's one seems to be faster.

Answer (score 2):

In the future, please show some code demonstrating that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself, showing where you got stuck, where the output is not as expected, etc.  Questions resembling "Here are my requirements.  Code this for me" generally aren't well-received around here.  How you got an upvote without showing any code is beyond me, but *c'est la vie*.

In this instance, I found the problem interesting, so I thought I'd go ahead and get you started. Challenge: accepted.  Here's one way to do it.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "series=1 2 3 4 5 6"

:loop

echo %series%

if "%series%"=="44 45 46 47 48 49" goto :EOF

for /f "tokens=1-6" %%a in ("%series%") do (
    set /a i1=%%a, i2=%%b, i3=%%c, i4=%%d, i5=%%e, i6=%%f+1

    if !i6! gtr 49 set /a i5+=1, i6=i5+1
    if !i5! gtr 48 set /a i4+=1, i5=i4+1, i6=i5+1
    if !i4! gtr 47 set /a i3+=1, i4=i3+1, i5=i4+1, i6=i5+1
    if !i3! gtr 46 set /a i2+=1, i3=i2+1, i4=i3+1, i5=i4+1, i6=i5+1
    if !i2! gtr 45 set /a i1+=1, i2=i1+1, i3=i2+1, i4=i3+1, i5=i4+1, i6=i5+1

    set "series=!i1! !i2! !i3! !i4! !i5! !i6!"
)

goto loop
```

Here's another solution that should be more efficient.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "series=1 2 3 4 5 6"
set total=0

for /L %%a in (1,1,44) do (

    set /a i2 = %%a + 1
    for /L %%b in (!i2!, 1, 45) do (

        set /a i3 = %%b + 1
        for /L %%c in (!i3!, 1, 46) do (

            set /a i4 = %%c + 1
            for /L %%d in (!i4!, 1, 47) do (

                set /a i5 = %%d + 1
                for /L %%e in (!i5!, 1, 48) do (

                    set /a i6 = %%e + 1
                    for /L %%f in (!i6!, 1, 49) do (

    rem // Uncomment this echo to watch the progress (severely decreases efficiency)
                        rem echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f
                        set /a total += 1
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    echo Total so far: !total!
)
rem // Should have gone through 13983816 iterations
```